# When should I use List of Data objects versus a ListData object?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Assume that I have AnimalData and AnimalListData:

```
<bean class="com.chang.data.AnimalData">
    <property name="name" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <property name="weight" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
</bean>

<bean class="com.chang.data.AnimalListData">
    <property name="animals" type="java.util.List&lt;com.chang.data.AnimalData>"/>
</bean>
```

If I create ZooData with a list of AnimalData, is it a better to use a List of Data objects (Approach #1) or a ListData object (Approach #2)? When should I use Approach #1 or Approach #2? How about for WsDTOs? Is the case the same?

Approach #1:

```
<bean class="com.chang.data.ZooData">
    <property name="animals" type="java.util.List&lt;com.chang.data.AnimalData>"/>
</bean>
```

Approach #2:

```
<bean class="com.chang.data.ZooData">
    <property name="animals" type="com.chang.data.AnimalListData"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Since it's DTO/Data objects, it doesn't make much difference here. I would prefer Approach #1, which is easy to get the list of objects.

Comment: Why would you create a class to keep  a `List` state **only** ? In my opinion it's not a good approach whatever the situation is. Approach #1 is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make a great deal of difference in my opinion, so some of this is personal preference.  The thing I would think about is: in approach 2 you have to do zooData.getAnimals().getAnimals(), whereas in approach 1 it is zooData.getAnimals().  The same applies for the DTOs point.  So approach 1 seems more intuitive to me .....

Answer (score 1):

***Approach #2***.

Think from a real-world mapping perspective. Do you actually have a real-world object `AnimalListData`?
`AnimalData`, on the other hand, is actually a real-world object that can directly be mapped to get detail of the animal.
 The list is just an *abstract construct* that you have created to simplify your programming otherwise it does not exist.